# Meteor.defer() not in official documentation?

Tags: node.js, meteor

I've just learned about the method

```
Meteor.defer(function() {
  // Do something
});
```

over at https://bulletproofmeteor.com, which according to them is short for:

```
Meteor.setTimeout(function() {
  // Do something
}, 0);
```

However, I found nothing about this function in the [Official Meteor Documentation](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_absoluteurl). Is there any reason for this not being in there despite it being part of the core?

Comment: Generally when something is present but not part of the doc, it means "Yeah, we did put that here. We may remove it anytime tho". Maybe it's just a short-hand for [`_.defer`](http://underscorejs.org/#defer)...

Comment: I see. It'd be a shame if they'd take it out though. Seems super useful!


Underscore needs to be added manually through atmosphere if I'm not mistaken, but it does seem to do the exact same thing yes.

Comment: Nope! Underscore.js is a core package and is available globally or through `api.use('underscore')`.

Comment: Oh really? Could've sworn I added it manually in the Discover Meteor book. Good to know! Thx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's been raised before and is tracked as an issue here: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/2176

The short answer is they haven't gotten around to documenting all functions, and this one isn't considered very important because it's basically just a shorthand.

Comment: Thanks! I was unable to find anything about it through google.